android studio,mantener una conexion abierta para consultas
os cuento.
estoy haciendo una app con android Studio y necesito conectar esta app a un servidor a traves de una ip y un puerto.
Como suele pasar esto me da problemas ANR y lo intente resolver con un AsincTask y con un Executor pero me sigue dando problemas ya que necesito mantener esta conexion abierta para desde la activity principal ir pasando y recuoperando informacion del servidor.
La conexion no es problema (la hago desde una clase JAVA que extiende el AsincRTask y lo llamo desde el activity de Kotlin), lo que me sucede es que despues de conectar, en unos 5 segundos, se me bloquea la app y me da el error ANR
el codigo Java de la conexion es este:
public void connectServer() {
    
    try {
        socketClient = new Socket(host, port);
        new Thread(this::serverListener).start();
        System.out.println("Conected");
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

y la funcion de Kotlin donde se llama a la conexion es esta:
public fun Connection(view: View){
    val text= iPEdit.getText().toString()       
    Log.i("info", "ip: "+text)
    val client= Client(text);
    client.execute();
}

alguna idea?
Gracias!!

Lo que ocurre más que nada es un problema de enfoque, porque este tipo de tareas no suelen hacerse así. Lo que se suele hacer es: 1. Desde el servidor remoto exponer los datos mediante una API o un Servicio Web o un servicio RESTful; 2. Desde Android, consultar los datos remotos accediendo al punto o los puntos de entrada mediante los que expones los datos en el servidor remoto (esto se hace mediante una URL); 3. Para determinar cuándo hay datos nuevos debes crear cierta lógica, tanto en el servidor remoto como en Android y escribir un código basado en Workmanager (Android) ...

... que consulte cada X tiempo (el mínimo es cada 15 minutos, pero puede ser cada hora, cada X horas, días, semanas, meses) el estado de los datos remotos con respecto a tus datos en local, sincronizando lo que haya que sincronizar. Hacerlo así, aunque de entrada parece complicado, es la forma correcta, por varios motivos: optimización de los recursos, tanto en el cliente (Android) como en el servidor, por ejemplo,  sincronización en 2º plano; seguridad, porque no tienes que tener abiertas conexiones remotas a tu base de datos; simplicidad, aunque la curva de aprendizaje pueda ser empinada.

wow.... si que parece complicado ahun que lo voy a explorar, pero mi problema es el siguiente, yo lo necesito para dar ordenes a un hardware al cual me conecto con la ip y el puerto, no necesito consultar sus datos sino pasarle yo datos a el enforma de ordenes. es por eso que no me sirve un servicio web y que necesito mantener abierta esta conexion para pasar datos segun pulse botones en mi app....

Eso también lo puedes hacer con el Servicio Web, y es más seguro, y también más simple, una vez lo tengas implementado. Pulsas el botón, el servidor recibe lo que le hayas enviado y procesa lo indicado en eso que hayas enviado. Y puedes hacer cosas como programar tareas. Supongamos que necesitas que cada media hora el servidor haga algo, desde Android, con Workmanager programas una tarea que se ejecute cada 30 minutos, recoja los datos que sea y los pase al servidor. Eso queda programado y no tienes siquiera que abrir la aplicación ...

... la tarea se ejecuta sola, aunque la aplicación Android esté cerrada o en segundo plano. Y es que hay otras complicaciones que estás herramientas te van a ayudar a solucionar. Por eso decía que la curva de aprendizaje es empinada, pero una vez llegado a la cima, todo son ventajas: a disfrutar del paisaje. Pongamos un ejemplo: ¿qué pasa si cuando debe ejecutarse ese código no hay conexión a internet o el dispositivo está apagado o no tiene batería? ¿Cómo se retoma eso? Si no usas esa herramientas, debes programar tú esa lógica, lo cual complica todo...

... Pero Workmanager se encarga de eso. Si no hay conexión, o no hay batería suficiente, la tarea se reprograma para ejecutarse en cuanto se den las condiciones necesarias para ello. Y no digamos nada de la optimización. ¿Cómo vas a hacer para tener esos recursos escuchando siempre, tanto en la App Android como en el servidor? Esa lógica también tienes que programarla, y aunque lo logres sin error, puede que necesites consumir muchos recursos para que eso funcione. Con Wormanager + Servicio Web todo queda solucionado de una manera limpia. Te aseguro que vale la pena usar este enfoque.

ok, vamos a ello pues... voy a estudiar lo que me dices y a ver si consigo enfocarlo asi...!

Esta es la documentación inicial para Workmanager. Para el Servicio Web necesitarás también Retrofit u otra biblioteca para hacer peticiones remotas. Y más adelante puede que necesites inyección de dependencia con Hilt. Son todas herramientas nuevas que te pueden sonar a chino en principio, pero que te van a facilitar el trabajo. Como dije antes, vale la pena emprender una cuesta de aprendizaje empinada, no verás resultados inmediatos, pero cuando incorpores todo eso, verás lo simple que son cosas complicadas.

Ok! gracias por tu tiempo!
